# linking objective c++

Tags: c++, objective-c, linker, gnustep

I am trying to figure out why when I convert my main.m file to a main.mm file, it no longer will link properly.

I have reduces the problem to the following example code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
int main( int argc, const char ** argv ) {
return NSApplicationMain( argc, argv);
}
```

I am using gnustep and linux.  I enter the following commands and everything works as expected:

g++ -g -c main.m -I/usr/GNUstep/Local/Library/Headers -I/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers

g++ -g -o test main.o -L/usr/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries -L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lgnustep-base -lgnustep-gui

Now if I rename main.m to main.mm and use these two commands ( same exept main.m now main.mm):

g++ -g -c main.mm -I/usr/GNUstep/Local/Library/Headers -I/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers

g++ -g -o test main.o -L/usr/GNUstep/Local/Library/Libraries -L/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lgnustep-base -lgnustep-gui

I get the following error:
main.mm:7: undefined reference to `NSApplicationMain(int, char const**)'

Can someone please find what I am doing wrong?  I do not see why it is now failing to link.

I am trying to add some C++ classes to an objective c program and this is preventing me from continuing.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you compile it as C++, the compiler [mangles the name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) of the symbol `NSApplicationMain`, so it can't find it, since it's looking for something like `__Z17NSApplicationMainiPPKc`.  You can use the `nm` program (from binutils) to see what symbols the object files are referencing:

```
$ # When compiled as Objective-C:
$ nm main.o | grep NSApplicationMain
                 U NSApplicationMain
$ # When compiled as Objective-C++:
$ nm main.o | grep NSApplicationMain
                 U _Z17NSApplicationMainiPPKc
```

In order to avoid this problem, C functions need to be declared with an [`extern "C"`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.3) modifier in order to tell the compiler not to mangle the name.  Looking into `<AppKit/NSApplication.h>`, the header file where `NSApplicationMain` is declared, I see this:

```
APPKIT_EXPORT int
NSApplicationMain(int argc, const char **argv);
```

Alas, `APPKIT_EXPORT` is defined to be one of `extern`, `__declspec(dllexport)`, `extern __declspec(dllexport)`, or nothing in `<AppKit/AppKitDefines.h>`.  Since it's also used for global variable declarations, we can't get around this by redefining it to `extern "C"` (which would be extremely hacky and kludgy anyways).  The AppKit header files do not seem to contain any `extern "C"` declarations at all, although I do see them in various header files under `Foundation/` and `GNUStepBase/`.

So what can you do?  The solution is to wrap your includes with an `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C"
{
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
}

int main( int argc, const char ** argv ) {
  return NSApplicationMain( argc, argv);
}
```

This will give the functions defined in those header files the proper linkage, and it will all work out.  But you shouldn't have to do this -- I would file a bug report with GNUstep, telling them to add proper `extern "C"` declarations to their header files.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the name mangling c++ compilers typically use to enable function overloading at the link stage.

C++ defines a `extern "C"` directive that forces it to use a C compatible name for a function.

You can use it in a C++ file like so :-

```
  // this makes func use a C compatible linkage
  extern "C" void func(int a)
  {
```

In a header file that is included by C and C++ it is necessary to protect the extern "C" declaration from C, and the C compiler does not under stand it.

```
#ifndef EXTERN_C
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERN_C extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERN_C
#endif
#endif
// Use it like this to declare a Function with C linkage
EXTERN_C void func(int a);
// If you have a lot of functions and declarations that need to be C compatible
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
//functions with C linkage
void func(int a);
...
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Now, how does this help your problem? Well, main.mm means the Foundation.h and AppKit.h files are being compiled as C++. Why Apple have not protected NSApplicationMain with a extern "C" directive I cannot guess, but it clearly isn't guarded.

A simple, if brutal, fix would be to alter your #imports like follows:

```
extern "C" {
// All declarations inside this block will use C linkage
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
}

int main( int argc, const char ** argv ) {
  return NSApplicationMain( argc, argv);
}
```